# Open Source MRI Image Dataset

Tags: data-request, medical, images

I'm working on a voxel-based modelling application and one of the features that I've implemented is a method to do a 3D mesh reconstruction from a series of 2D image slices (similar to an MRI). I've got a basic brain scan image set that I've been working on, but ultimately I'd like to release a small demo example showing how to do the mesh reconstruction. However, in order to do this I need the images to be legally open source so that I'm not distributing images that have copy right restrictions. I've scoured the net trying to find a suitable image set but haven't been able to find anything.

Does anyone have any resources they could point me to that I could use for my application?

Answer (score 4):

Can you find something on [OpenfMRi](https://openfmri.org/)?

> > "The OpenfMRI project was established in 2010 to provide a resource for researchers interested in making their fMRI data openly available to the research community."

There are 34 datasets at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Another place to obtain MRIs: http://www.cancerimagingarchive.net/

Answer (score 1):

Just released (11.2018)

https://fastmri.med.nyu.edu/ (access by request)

> The anonymized imaging dataset provided by NYU Langone comprises raw k-space data from more than 1,500 fully sampled knee MRIs obtained on 3 and 1.5 Tesla magnets and DICOM images from 10,000 clinical knee MRIs also obtained at 3 or 1.5 Tesla. Curation of these datasets are part of an IRB approved study. The raw dataset includes coronal proton density-weighted images with and without fat suppression. The DICOM dataset contains coronal proton density-weighted with and without fat suppression, axial proton density-weighted with fat suppression, sagittal proton density, and sagittal T2-weighted with fat suppression. Raw and DICOM data have been anonymized via conversion to the vendor-neutral ISMRMD format and the RSNA clinical trial processor, respectively. We also performed manual inspection of each DICOM image for the presence of any unexpected protected health information (PHI), with spot checking of both metadata and image content.

[Hacknews post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18548132) and [article](https://www.radiologybusiness.com/topics/artificial-intelligence/nyu-facebook-release-knee-mri-dataset-ai)

[Press statement](https://www.newswise.com/articles/view/704368/?sc=c98)

Answer (score 0):

The Nature paper "Multi-modal ultra-high resolution structural 7-Tesla MRI data repository" [lists](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201450#data-records) two data sources for high resolution MRI structural scans of human brains:

> All data records listed in this section are available from NITRIC (Data Citation 1: NITRC http://www.nitrc.org/projects/atag_mri_scans/) or Dryad (Data Citation 2: Dryad http://doi.org/10.5061/dryad.fb41s). A README file with a detailed description of the content of all downloads is available in Dryad. Additional material and information are also provided in Data Citation 1: NITRC http://www.nitrc.org/projects/atag_mri_scans/ and Data Citation 2: Dryad http://doi.org/10.5061/dryad.fb41s.